# In "Ready Player One", how does Halliday die?

Tags: ready-player-one, ernest-cline

I was looking back at *Ready Player One* by Ernest Cline and I wondering the following:

How did James Halliday die? Was it related to his creations?

Answer (score 2):

The same question has been [asked and answered](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/87855/27759) on another Stack Exchange site. I can't do much more than provide the same quotes given over there, from Chapter 1 of the book (emphasis mine):

> Halliday now stands at the front of a funeral parlor, next to an open casket. A second, much older Halliday lies inside the casket, his body emaciated and ravaged by cancer. Shiney quarters cover each of his eyelids.

And, from earlier, hinting at why the cancer had been able to emaciate and ravage his body rather than being treatable:

> He had died a sixty-seven-year-old bachelor, with no living relatives, and by most accounts, without a single friend. He'd spent the last fifteen years of his life in self-imposed isolation, during which time - if the rumors were to be believed - he'd gone completely insane.

Which suggests that he may not have cared to seek treatment, knowing that he was going to die and not having anything left to live for.